# Unable to generate JMockit code coverage report

Tags: jmockit

I have added all the configuration details regarding code coverage using jmockit in build.xml but it doesn't generate any report.

This is my configuration code:

```
<target name="tests" depends="testscompile,mkdirtests_clean,mkdirtests">
   <junit fork="yes"  forkmode="once" haltonfailure="no"  printsummary="yes" >

    <jvmarg value="-javaagent:../JUnitlib/jmockit.jar"/> 

    <sysproperty key="jmockit-coverage-output" value="html"/>
    <sysproperty key="jmockit-coverage-outputDir" value="${reports.dir}"/>
    <sysproperty key="jmockit-coverage-srcDirs" value="${src}"/>
    <sysproperty key="jmockit-coverage-metrics" value="all"/>
    <classpath>
     <pathelement location="${classes}" />     
     <pathelement location="../JUnitlib/jmockit.jar" />
     <pathelement location="../JUnitlib/junit-4.12.jar" />
     <pathelement location="../JUnitlib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
     <fileset dir="../WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
     <include name="**/*.jar"/>
     </fileset>
     <fileset dir="${tomcat.root}">
      <include name="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
     </fileset>
    </classpath>

    <batchtest todir="${docs.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${classes}">
    <include name="**/*Test.class" />
    </fileset>
     </batchtest>
        <formatter type="xml"/>

      </junit>

<!-- Junit Report generation -->

   <junitreport todir="${reports.dir}">
          <fileset dir="${docs.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
          </fileset>
      <report todir="${reports.dir}" />
        </junitreport>

   <antcall target="report.zip"/>
  </target>
```

Here in this configuration reports for junit test and code coverage need to be generated but only junit test reports are only generates. Where i am going wrong please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

The JMockit code coverage tool is in its own jar, `jmockit-coverage.jar`, not in `jmockit.jar` (although this will probably change in the next release or so).

The build script should remove the `jvmarg` line, and add a new `pathelement` for that separate jar.